# How to access Amazon EMR error message with Python

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-emr

I am running EMR clusters kicked off with Airflow and I need some way of passing error messages back to Airflow. Airflow runs in Python so I need this to be done in python.

Currently the error logs are in the "Log URI" section under configuration details. Accessing this might be one way to do it, but any way to access the error logs from emr with python would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which operator do you use? By "passing error messages back" you mean to raise it in Airflow or show it in tasks logs?

Comment: I mean I want to be able to search the logs and do actions on it in the Airflow code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the EMR logs in S3 with [boto3 for example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object).
The S3 path would be:

- stderr : `s3://<EMR_LOG_BUCKET_DEFINED_IN_EMR_CONFIGURATION>/logs/<CLUSTER_ID>/steps/<STEP_ID>/stderr.gz`
- stout : `s3://<EMR_LOG_BUCKET_DEFINED_IN_EMR_CONFIGURATION>/logs/<CLUSTER_ID>/steps/<STEP_ID>/stdout.gz`
- controller : `s3://<EMR_LOG_BUCKET_DEFINED_IN_EMR_CONFIGURATION>/logs/<CLUSTER_ID>/steps/<STEP_ID>/controller.gz`
- syslog : `s3://<EMR_LOG_BUCKET_DEFINED_IN_EMR_CONFIGURATION>/logs/<CLUSTER_ID>/steps/<STEP_ID>/syslog.gz`

Cluster ID and Step ID can be passed to your different tasks via XCOM from the task(s) that creates the cluster/steps.

Warning for spark (might be applicable to other types of steps):
This works if you submit your steps in client mode as if you are using cluster mode you would need to change the URL to fetch the application logs of the driver instead.